# Can we predict future values of a dataset with logistic regression in python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I'm using logistic regression to predict the accuracy and other features of a dataset with sklearn LogisticRegression. I was wondering if there's a way to predict future values with logistic regression. I know it would be easy to do with linear regression but I feel it wouldn't be as efficient as a logistic regression prediction.

This is how I trained my dataset:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
import datetime
clf_lr = LogisticRegression(solver='lbfgs', multi_class="multinomial", max_iter=1000, random_state=1)

def train_model(clf, X_train, y_train, epochs=10):
"""
   Cette fonction entraîne un model spécifié et retourne une liste 
   de résultats.

   :param clf: modèle scikit learn
   :param X_train: données d'entraînement encodés (attributs)
   :param y_train: données d'entraînement (classe à prédire)
   :param epochs: défault = 10, nombre d'itérations
   :return: résultats (accuracy) pour les données d'entraînement
   """
   scores = []
   print("Starting training...")
   for i in range(1, epochs + 1):
       print("Epoch:" + str(i) + "/" + str(epochs) + " -- " + str(datetime.datetime.now()))
       clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
       score = clf.score(X_train, y_train)
       scores.append(score)
   print("Done training.")
   return scores
```

Answer (score 2):

Use logistic regression if you have two classes, like `0` or `1`, or `boy` or `girl`. Use linear regression if you have continuous target values, like `height`.

Your question is better suited for [Stats Stack Exchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com). Stack Overflow is for code related problems.

Comment: What if I have a dataset of some stock prices?

Comment: That would be a continuous target, so linear regression.